# Have a universal php.ini redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering on how to make a rewrite rule that redirects www.domain.com/php.ini to www.domain.com, in a way its usable for any domain.

The solution I am looking for is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but to rewrite redirects www.domain.com/php.ini to www.domain.com